# Instantiating a class, then using it in another thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, constructor

Consider two threads: *threadA* and *threadB*. (E.g. let *threadA* be the UI thread, and let *threadB* an own subclass of `Thread`.) Regarding **data visibility**, is it safe to instantiate a class in *threadA*, pass it to the constructor of *threadB*, and then use it exclusively from *threadB*? Let me clarify this with code. (Note that the code is simplified, so this architecture makes sense in the real application in its actual form.)

```
public class SomeClass {
    public SomeClass(....) {
       // initialization
    }
}

public class MyCustomThread extends Thread {
    public MyCustomThread(SomeClass someClass) {
        mSomeClass = someClass;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
           // operate on mSomeClass         
    }
}
```

And the method that starts everything is as follows (its location is irrelevant). This is called by *threadA*.

```
public void launchThread() {
   SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
   MyCustomThread threadB = new MyCustomThread(someClass); // MyCustomThread is a subclass of Thread
   threadB.start();
   // After this point, threadA never accesses someClass,
   // and only threadB is operating on it
}
```

I know that constructors are not allowed to be synchronized, and no synchronized code is needed inside it (because the *this* reference -- unless leaked out -- is not available to other threads until the class is constructed in its creator thread). So my question is about data visibility: is the code safe, provided I don't access `someClass` (and any of its referenced data) from *threadA* after `threadB.start()` is called?

In other words, will `threadB.run()` see the most up-to-date versions of `someClass` data (such as fields, internal references, etc.)? My guess: since there will be no external change on `someClass` after *threadB* accesses `someClass` for the first time, *threadB* must see the correct values, because **it can't have cached copies from before**. So, for the above reason, I don't need to access `someClass` in a synchronized block from `threadB.run()`. (Again, note that it's guaranteed that *threadA* doesn't access `someClass` after *threadB* is started.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're saying that, after `threadB.start()`, the instance referred to by `someClass` will no longer be modified by any other thread: yes, `threadB.run()` will see the latest version.

There's really no concurrency/race-condition that could occur in this scenario. Everything is happening sequentially, you simply have objects that are `Thread`s which I think might be causing you to be slightly paranoid :).

Comment: ThreadA is modifying the object in question and THEN starting the second thread: there is only one order of execution here. ThreadA creates the object, potentially modifies it, gives it to ThreadB, potentially modifies it more, then B starts. There's no place for any context switches or any other event of the like to cause an anomaly.

Comment: @LuxuryMode: I see cklab already answered, but here is the same thing with different words: if *someClass.foo = "bar"* is called **after** *threadB.start()* is called, then you're right, threadB might see an outdated copy. But in my software, it's ensured that *someClass* is not touched after *threadB.start()* is called.

Comment: Actually, my paranoia was because run() accesses data that were created by another thread. And since threadB is a different thread, it might have cached copies of these data. But since this is the first time it accesses those data, it can't have cached copies.

Comment: All the threads in a multithreaded single-process program share the same address space, so you don't have to worry about the cache.  (Thankfully - otherwise multithreading would be even harder than it already is!)