# Running Multiple Threads Freezing Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to instantiate a class on a separate thread from my first one, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321005/instantiating-a-class-then-using-it-in-another-thread), which works, using it like this:

```
private class PongThread extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        new Pong(WINDOW);
    }
}
```

And instantiating like this:

```
new PongThread().start();
```

The problem is that if I try to instantiate it twice, then the program just stops responding. So how do I do this so that I can make a new `PongThread` as many times as I want?

**EDIT:**

My Pong class is a LWJGL Display running with a while loop and the `sync(FPS)` method:

```
while(isRunning) {

    //Logic and rendering method calls, etc.

    Display.update();
    Display.sync(30);
}
```

**EDIT #2:**

My pong class contains and uses private classes (I don't know if that might affect it)

Comment: Show the Class `Pong`.

Comment: if you use some static data inside Pong class and you didn't synchronize it, that could cause it...

Comment: @kirbyquerby, WINDOW is my JFrame, I am passing it so that I could minimize it, etc. if I wanted to (I know that it should not be capitalised like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display class from LWJGL is a [static class](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html) and I'm not sure if you can use it separately for different threads. Try using [JOGL](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) instead. It has more capabilities then LWJGL and it has much better support then LWJGL.